# Combine PDF with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to combine an array of PDF into one with this code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fusion_PDFs(ByVal name As String, ByRef pdfs() As Variant)

Dim oPDDoc() As Object
Dim oPDDocFinal As Object
Dim Num As Long
Dim i As Integer

    Set oPDDocFinal = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    oPDDocFinal.Open (pdfs(0))

    ReDim oPDDoc(UBound(pdfs))

    For i = LBound(pdfs) + 1 To UBound(pdfs)

        Set oPDDoc(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        oPDDoc(i).Open (pdfs(i))

    Next i

    For i = LBound(oPDDoc) To UBound(oPDDoc)

        Num = oPDDocFinal.GetNumPages() - 1

        oPDDocFinal.InsertPages Num, oPDDoc(i), 0, oPDDoc(i).GetNumPages(), True

    Next i


    oPDDocFinal.Save 1, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DRT créés\" & name & ".pdf"

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For i = LBound(oPDDoc) To UBound(oPDDoc)

        oPDDoc(i).Close
        Set oPDDoc(i) = Nothing

    Next i

    oPDDocFinal.Close
    Set oPDDocFinal = Nothing

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I got a string array from another function which contains X path of pdfs. I already verified this array and there is nothing wrong with it, the problem is on this code. But i did a test version before rework it to works with my project, and the test version was working perfectly. The code is still very similar and i didn't change nothing on the creation and the fusion parts.

I first open an oPDDocFinal, which is the first pdf of my array "pdfs" (pdfs(0)) then i loop on the rest of the pdfs array to create a PDDoc array. Finally i loop on this PDDoc array to combine one by one all theses pdf with the oPDDocFinal.

But i got an error on this line :

```
oPDDocFinal.InsertPages Num, oPDDoc(i), 0, oPDDoc(i).GetNumPages(), True
```

i got the following error (i tried to translate from french) :

Execution error '91' :

Object variable or With bloc variable undefined

I didn't modified this part of code and it was working on my test script, but now i get this error. Do you know how can i solve my problem ?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'd be curios to know what the value of `i` is at that point. My first suspicion is that `oPDDoc(I)` is out of bound and not an object.

Comment: Ok you touched something. I tried to display all theses variables (i, num and oPDDoc.GetNumPages()) in a MsgBox and the error deported on this new line. I found that my oPDDoc is the problem, it's seems to wasn't get defined... But the path i putted in parameter of the oPDDoc.Open is correct, i tested all of them one by one with a MsgBox. Is there any way to test if the open function was a success ? By the way, thanks for your answer !

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.100.html), `open` returns -1 if it fails. Try checking the return value like this: `intResult = oPDDocFinal.Open (pdfs(0))`

Comment: Thanks Tim, i found my error ! Check out my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found my error :

My first loop, i start at 1, so i take pdfs(1) to oPDDoc(1), but my first loop start at 0 so oPDDoc(0) doesn't exists.

I fixed it like that, and now it works :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fusion_PDFs(ByVal name As String, ByRef pdfs() As Variant)

Dim oPDDoc() As Object
Dim oPDDocFinal As Object
Dim Num As Long
Dim i As Integer

    Set oPDDocFinal = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    oPDDocFinal.Open (pdfs(0))

    ReDim oPDDoc(UBound(pdfs))

    For i = LBound(pdfs) + 1 To UBound(pdfs)

        Set oPDDoc(i - 1) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        oPDDoc(i - 1).Open (pdfs(i))

    Next i


    For i = LBound(oPDDoc) To UBound(oPDDoc) - 1

        Num = oPDDocFinal.GetNumPages() - 1

        oPDDocFinal.InsertPages Num, oPDDoc(i), 0, oPDDoc(i).GetNumPages(), True

    Next i


    oPDDocFinal.Save 1, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DRT créés\" & name & ".pdf"

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'For i = LBound(oPDDoc) To UBound(oPDDoc) - 1
    '
    '    oPDDoc(i).Close
    '   Set oPDDoc(i) = Nothing
    '
    'Next i
    '
    'oPDDocFinal.Close
    'Set oPDDocFinal = Nothing

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thanks all for your attention !

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:-

- Does the environment that it is not working on have the same version of AcroExch and Word installed
- Can both environments see the PDFs?
- Is there contention of oPDDocFinal meaning something or someone else has it open ([This thread](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/AcroExch-error-q6750.aspx) implies it should be closed to update).
- In debug, does oPDDoc(i) have a value
- should it be bracketed - `oPDDocFinal.InsertPages(Num, oPDDoc(i), 0, oPDDoc(i).GetNumPages(), True)`

I also believe you may have an easier debugging in a single loop.

```
Dim oPDDoc      As Object
Dim oPDDocFinal As Object
Dim Num         As Long
Dim i           As Integer

'Initialise objects
Set oPDDocFinal = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

'Save a working copy
oPDDocFinal.Open (pdfs(0))
oPDDocFinal.Save 1, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DRT créés\" & name & ".pdf"
oPDDocFinal.Close

'Reference the working copy
pdfs(0) = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DRT créés\" & name & ".pdf"

'for all but the first item in the pdfs array
For i = LBound(pdfs) + 1 To UBound(pdfs)

    'Open the working copy
    oPDDocFinal.Open (pdfs(0))

    'Open the additional PDF
    oPDDoc.Open (pdfs(i))

    'Get the page count of the working copy
    Num = oPDDocFinal.GetNumPages() - 1

    'Insert the additional PDF at the end of the working copy
    oPDDocFinal.InsertPages Num, oPDDoc(i), 0, oPDDoc(i).GetNumPages(), True

   'Close the additional PDF
   oPDDoc.Close

   'Save and close the working copy PDF
   oPDDocFinal.Save
   oPDDocFinal.Close 

Next i

'Release objects
 Set oPDDocFinal = Nothing
 Set oPDDoc = Nothing
```

This would be a heavyweight loop but should act as a starting point to debugging. I should also add I do not have `AcroExch`. The above is theoretical.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your answer, i solved my problem and you seems to have noticed the problem too. anyway i'll answer my own post to avoid any confusions.

Comment: @MaximeOzenne I'm glad you worked it out. I would still recommend using a single loop and closing and releasing (`Set oPDDocFinal = Nothing`) resources as you go can help with stability and debugging..